# Firefox warning about sameSite Cookies while I do some Ajax polling from my website to itself

Tags: ajax, firefox, samesite

I'm developing a collaborative game for covid-19 confined people where players unveil together an image hidden by tiles. Each player can click a tile and try and solve an associated riddle.
There are no cookies involved, and the player's name is stored in the url via GET and saved in a SQL database with PHP for the first player unveiling a given tile. I ask the user's browser via JavaScript to check every 5 seconds the number of tiles unveiled, with the Ajax command XMLHttpRequest requesting a file that stores this number and resides in the same folder as the web page in website's filesystem. If this number has changed then I force a reload of the page via JavaScript. Unfortunately one effect of the XMLHttpRequest seems to be that my website sends a cookie to the user. And Firefox complains about this in the developper console:

> Cookie “PHPNET-MNO” will be soon rejected because it has the
>   “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the
>   “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

After reading on the Internet for 3 hours about XMLHttpRequest and about cookie sameSite policies, I still don't know what to do. Should I just ignore the warning? Or try and fix it? Or change my approach (I'd be happy to if there is a simple alternative)?

Note: Chrome does not complain.

Comment: Can you look at the Network tab in the Firefox / Chrome DevTools and share the contents of the `set-cookie` header for the `PHPNET-MNO` cookie?

Comment: set-cookie: PHPNET-MNO=11110|XtQb1|XtQbt; path=/